# On $k$-extendability of bipartite states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Definition of $k$-extendability can be given as follows.

> Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. A state $\rho_{AB}$ on a bipartite Hilbert space
>   $\mathrm{A}\otimes\mathrm{B}$ is $k$-extendible with respect to
>   $\mathrm{B}$ if there exists a state $\rho_{AB^k}$ on
>   $\mathrm{A}\otimes\mathrm{B}^{\otimes k}$ which is invariant under any
>   permutation of the $\mathrm{B}$ subsystems and such that
>   $\rho_{AB}=\mathrm{Tr}_{B^{k-1}}\rho_{AB^k}$.

Further a result of Doherty et al ([Phys. Rev. A. 69:022308](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.69.022308)) gives that,

> A state on a bipartite Hilbert space $\mathrm{A}\otimes\mathrm{B}$ is
>   separable if and only if it is $k$-extendible with respect to
>   $\mathrm{B}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

If this is the case, then isn't a pure maximally entangled state (say $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$) is also extendable for all $k$? Consider the extension $|00\cdots0\rangle + |11\cdots1\rangle$ for some $k$. I think, I am missing some obvious point. Can someone please help?

Comment: A k-partite maximally entangled state is a pure state (symmetrical to permutations), but its partial trace over any of its components is no longer a pure state. In other words, the partial trace does not recover the pure bipartite maximally entangled state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you figure this works:

> isn't a pure maximally entangled state (say $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$) is also extendable for all $k$? Consider the extension $|00\cdots0\rangle + |11\cdots1\rangle$ for some $k$.

Take $k=2$ and
$$
\rho_{AB^2}=\frac12\left(\vphantom{\sum}|000⟩+|111⟩\right)\left(\vphantom{\sum}⟨000|+⟨111|\right),
$$
as it seems that you're proposing, and calculate
\begin{align}
{\mathrm{Tr}_{B^1}}\!\!\left(\rho_{AB^2}\right)
& =
\frac12\mathrm{Tr}_{3}\!\!\left(\vphantom{\sum}|000⟩+|111⟩\right)\left(\vphantom{\sum}⟨000|+⟨111|\right)
\\& =
\frac12\mathrm{Tr}_{3}\!\!\left(\vphantom{\sum}
|000⟩⟨000|+|000⟩⟨111|+|111⟩⟨000|+|111⟩⟨111|
\right)
\\& =
\frac12\left(\vphantom{\sum}
|00⟩⟨00|+|11⟩⟨11|
\right).
\end{align}
This is a completely mixed state, having lost all coherence to the vanishing traces $\mathrm{Tr}\:|1⟩⟨0|=\mathrm{Tr}\:|0⟩⟨1|=0$ on the cross terms, and it has nothing at all to do with the pure state
$$
\rho_{AB}=\frac12\left(\vphantom{sum}|00⟩+|11⟩\right)\left(\vphantom{\sum}⟨00|+⟨11|\right)
$$
you were hoping for.

Moreover, this fits in perfectly well with the result you quote: the maximally entangled pure state is not separable, so no $k$-extension is possible.